# Google Play rejecting release apk as debuggable

Tags: phonegap-build

Google Play rejecting release apk as debuggable.

I have uploaded phonegap apk from https://build.phonegap.com/. Google play generate debuggable apk error . How to resolve this issue,

Comment: Did you sign the build with a Prod keystore file?

Comment: **Likely crossposted** on nitobi as: [Debug on site is disabled but while uploading to google play store it gives disable debugging? help](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/debug-on-site-is-disabled-but-while-uploading-to-google-play-store-it-gives-disable-debugging-help)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a signed apk.

This instructions are here: http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/signing_signing-android.md.html